# How to access the search menu 2.8? (used to be spacebar in 2.79)

Tags: interface, shortcut

In 2.79 the search menu is accessed pressing the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>

[image]

In 2.8 the space bar is used to play the timeline.

Where is the search menu now?

Answer (score 24):

To access the search menu in 2.8 press <kbd>F3</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting that there is an option in the User Preferences to change the spacebar action back to search (at least in an older 2.8 build I have).

Comment: Please explain how to do this on a mac since F3 on a mac opens mission control

Comment: @MicroMachine that would be Fn + F3 (macs have the F keys the secondary buttons.)

Comment: Can someone explain how to do this on a MacBook with a touchbar since there are no F keys?

Answer (score 22):

In 2.81 you can set the Spacebar Action in Preferences -> Keymap and set it back to 'Search'.

[image: Blender Preferences - Spacebar Action - Search]

Comment: Nice first answer! Welcome to the site.

Comment: This is what worked for me (no F keys on recent macbook with touchbar)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on for Windows users, holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> works as well.

Comment: For me that opens the windows search menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on mac without touchbar by holding the <kbd>fn</kbd> key which makes all the <kbd>F</kbd> keys appear. You can also change the search menu to appear by pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> like [DanP](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/85031/danp). mentioned on top.