# How to copy animation from one object to another on Mac

Tags: animation, shortcut, osx

I am trying to copy the animations from one object to the other and the Key command <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> does not bring anything up for me.

Is there any other way to access this menu, or is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> the only way? If so, what's the Mac version?

Comment: most commands can be accessed through the search menu. Press F3 and type link or any other command you are looking for. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141118/how-to-access-the-search-menu-2-8-used-to-be-spacebar-in-2-79/141119#141119

Comment: ctrl L should work for Mac as well, you can go in the header menu > Object > Make Links > Animation Data. With right click you can assign it a shortcut.